# Port Forwarding and static IP without router access

Tags: router, port-forwarding, home-networking, static-ip

I am living without access to my router or any webGUI, but I am trying to make a self hosted home server which I would like to open up and expose to the internet. I am would love to give myself a static ip or at least be able to port forward and setup a ddns. But I do have access to a LAN Port, this is it.

I wouldn't say I am a noob, but I am not very aware of network engineering and how it all works. I would love any help I can get from this, network related or not. I don't have a massive budget, so it would be great if the solution was under £100.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- What were you looking to host?
- What method are you using to connect the machine to the internet?
- Is this your network, or are you using somebody elses network?

Many residential services do not offer a static IP.

However it would be worth contacting your ISP -- some provide it, others may provide it as an optional add-on.

DynDNS services can be found freely, and you can also integrate DynDNS with other providers such as CloudFlare if required (via the use of scripts such as [cloudflare-ddns](https://github.com/adrienbrignon/cloudflare-ddns))

Hosting from home using a normal machine is often discouraged by many, however with the right expectations it is not a problem.

Provided that you understand it will not support many users (in most circumstances), and that consumer equipment tends not to have the same reliability -- then its fine.

Depending on your requirements, for example, if you only need to test something for development -- then you could also consider using a tool such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Answer (score 0):

With no router access to enable port forwarding, your router is going to block everything not going over the ports that it has whitelisted. Normally only 80,8080,993,465, etc. Your only option is to use a VPN to route over an open port and let the service on the other end handle it. Some VPN services offer hosted servers that can help you achieve all this, but DDNS is kind of a moot point without the ability to open other ports. Microsoft has some pretty cheap hosted servers you may be able to utilize.