# Can I set up a VPN server without router access?

Tags: router, vpn, home-networking

I want to be able to set up a Windows 10 PC so that I can connect to the internet remotely as if from the IP address of the PC. I do not have access to the router password (of the modem/router providing the internet to that PC).

Is this still possible?

For example, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1574103/728074) seems to suggest that default open ports might be able to be used.

Is this the case?

Comment: If you cannot configure port forwarding you will not be able to connect to the intranet VPN service from outside of your network.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to set up a Windows 10 PC so that I can connect to the internet remotely as if from the IP address of the PC. I do not have access to the router password (of the modem/router providing the internet to that PC). Is this still possible.

Directly, probably not, although you *may* have some luck using some UPnP IGD tool to configure a port-forward rule (that's how games and file-sharing apps open ports for inbound connections), as long as whoever manages the router hasn't disabled it.

(Keep in mind that just because you *can* configure the router, doesn't mean the configuration will be effective. For the modem/router to be able to forward packets to your PC, it must receive those packets itself first – and it's often the case these days that the customer's router no longer has a dedicated public IP address, in which case the (in)ability to configure port-forwarding is moot because there's no way to reach the router itself.)

But in such cases you can still have remote access indirectly – you can still use a third system that *both* devices connect to, and which relays the tunneled packets between the two devices. VPNs are not strictly one-to-one; a VPN server can always relay between two VPN clients. So if you rent a VPS and set up WireGuard or OpenVPN there, then configure your Windows PC to keep a persistent connection to that server, you get a similar result – although making one client access Internet through another will be a bit of a headache, but it's completely doable.

Aside from the usual 'server-client' VPN software, there are also 'mesh' or 'peer-to-peer' VPN tools such as ZeroTier that are far more suited for this kind of usage; often they don't require a central server (either having "NAT traversal" mechanisms to establish direct connections and/or public relay servers). However, the specific one I'd probably suggest is Tailscale, which has what it calls "[Exit Node](https://tailscale.com/kb/1103/exit-nodes)" configuration already built into its UI.

> For example, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1574103/728074) seems to suggest that default open ports might be able to be used. Is this the case?

No. The author of that answer seems to misunderstand that ports are distinct in both directions – people call a port "open" when they can connect out to that port number on the remote end, **and** people call a port "open" when they can receive inbound connections on that port on the local end, but those are completely separate things in every way, except for the terminology being used.

UDP and TCP packets have two separate fields for "source" and "destination" port, so a packet returning from a remote HTTP server is entirely different from a packet arriving to a local HTTP server, even though they both are "port 80" packets – but one has 80 as its source port, the other as destination port.

(And even if that weren't the case – most home routers are used mainly for their IPv4 NAT capability, hiding *multiple* internal devices behind a single public address, so a "default open" port still wouldn't be of much use if the router didn't know which internal address to forward those packets to. That's no longer an issue with IPv6, but still.)

Comment: Thanks! I think Tailscale may indeed be the right tool. I'm setting it up and if it works I will of course accept your answer.